# Saving video files using node youtube-dl with MeteorJS

Tags: node.js, video, meteor, youtube, youtube-dl

I've been doing some proof of concepts using youtube-dl and the [node module](https://github.com/fent/node-youtube-dl) to download youtube video files through a web interface.

I moved to [meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/) making my app reactive. At this point, I'm able to get video information, formats, and the video download seems to be working fine, but seems that the files is not being saved.

Does anybody tried to integrate youtube-dl or just worked with the filesystem using meteorJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found the error.

I was forgetting to add the pipe to write the file.

that's the missing part of the code.

`var output = path.join(path.resolve('.'), info.filename);`
`video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(output));`

I will edit this answer with the link to the full working app in github. I didn't uploaded yet.

Best!

Comment: Yes that was the solution, but unfortunately, the library it's too green respect of high definitions videos and youtube (audio and video are separated and couldn't get the merge working at this point).

That said, I suspended momentarily the project and pushed anything to github.